# Package that previously worked now unpacks with "non zero exit status"

Tags: r, install.packages, mlogit

A package that I previously used, "mlogit", is now not unpacking in R. I have manually typed it in as well as using the install packages tool. Although it says "successfully installed", it is not unpacked and does not show up in the Rstudio list of packages. This is what I get in the console:

> <U+2714> Package 'mlogit' successfully installed.
> Warning messages:
> 1: In utils::install.packages("Rdpack", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
> installation of package 'Rdpack' had non-zero exit status

> 2: In utils::install.packages("mlogit", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
> installation of package 'Rdpack' had non-zero exit status

> 3: In utils::install.packages("mlogit", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
> installation of package 'mlogit' had non-zero exit status

I had not updated R or switched computers, and all my files associated with this script are in the exact same place. I've run it a million times. Not sure what's different now. All other packages I've tried work. There are not alternative packages I can use for this purpose.

Comment: If it previously worked, why are you trying to reinstall it? You only ever need to run `install.packages()` once for a given pacakge, then you use `library()` to load that package when you need it. It would be better to give the complete log of messages from `install.packages()` to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: the package wasn't working on the updated version of R, since the package was updated and "mlogit" was obselete, I had someone else run it with the same issue, but switching back to the previous version fixed it. Thanks.